# Unexpected behaviour of the .Hidden property

Tags: excel, vba

quick description of what my code is supposed to do for clarity *(as there will be some external data used, making it harder to reproduce the issue)*.

My goal is to create a toggle button, that will switch between hiding and unhiding a data-table between its properties. These do work fine, but for some reason, **the `.Hidden` property of my range seems to return unexpected results, despite what should be considered it's obvious behaviour.**

My excel sheet looks like this:

[image]

And i want to toggle between hiding and unhiding the blue table.

---

```
Private Sub hide_button_Click()


    Dim copy_start As Integer
    Dim copy_end As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Summary")
    Dim tbl2 As ListObject: Set tbl2 = ws.ListObjects("t_sum2")



    copy_start = tbl2.HeaderRowRange.Row
    copy_end = tbl2.ListRows.Count + copy_start

   If (ws.Rows(copy_start & ":" & copy_end).EntireRow.Hidden = True) Then
       ws.Rows(copy_start & ":" & copy_end).EntireRow.Hidden = False
   Else
       ws.Rows(copy_start & ":" & copy_end).EntireRow.Hidden = True
   End If



End Sub
```

Seems pretty self-explanatory. So after compiling and running the procedure, **the blue table gets hidden as it is supposed to.**

[image]

However, after you run the procedure again. That table stays hidden and doesn't toggle between revealing the hidden rows.

Naturally I thought I was simply selecting my `copy_start`& `copy_end` ranges incorrectly. So I added these two following "debugging messages" to my code (before the if condition)

```
MsgBox(copy_start & vbNewLine & copy_end)
MsgBox(ws.Rows(copy_start & ":" & copy_end).EntireRow.Hidden)
```

To my own surprise, it returned the following results:

[image]
[image]

Which is absolutely baffling to me, especially the second `MsgBox` as to why it returns the `.Hidden` property as False, when you can clearly see, the `copy_start` and `copy_end` row ranges are calculated properly and they do match the blue table size: *(illustration)*

[image]

**Can anyone explain, why does essentially `Rows("21:34").EntireRow.Hidden` return as False, when they are infact really hidden?** (see fig. 2)

---

EDIT:

Perhaps one more detail I should disclose. Next to the tables there is a graph. I don't see how it should influence this operation, but maybe through some witchery...? I don't know

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use: `tbl2.Range.EntireRow.Hidden = Not tbl2.Range.EntireRow.Hidden`? Though, FWIW, your original code works for me in 2010.

Comment: @Rory yes it would, is oversight on my part. However it still only hides the blue table, but upon additional running, the table stays hidden and doesn't unhide

Comment: Check all the heighst of all rows in that range. all of them should be 0. Something like `For Each ThisRow In Rows("21:34").EntireRow
    Debug.Print ThisRow.EntireRow.Height
Next ThisRow` . If any of those rows height is not 0, then that would provoke `Hidden = False`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns all of them returned `12.75` Could you elaborate as to why it would return false?

Comment: I mean, check the height after hiding them. When a row is hidden, its height= 0. Right before unhide, check all the rows heights. If one of them is not 0,  unhide won't work because for Excel is not really hidden.

Comment: @Rawrplus - this is strange, I have managed to hide the table, using exactly your code and multiple other tables to a sheet. Can you replicate on a new Excel? Do you have any events?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, that's my point. It returns `12.75` even if seemingly hidden, And Vityata, yeah that's odd. I actually tried it on a new Sheet and it seems to work fine. Technically I am manipulating with the table in some other functions and procedures though

Comment: If it does not return 0, then for Excel those rows are not Hidden. That explains why you get `Hidden=False`. Maybe you hide them right, but then other part of the code or something manipulates those rows and they autofit or something. Just wondering. But indeed, if the height is not 0, then those rows are not hidden.

Comment: Well there is a graph next to the tables. Perhaps that could cause the issues? I edited my question accordingly (didn't disclose it at first, because I refused to believe it could somehow influence the procedure). It seems strange though, because I disclosed the cody fully. There is no external operation running during the procedure's rungtime

Comment: As @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns suggests, I also think it's the row height. If the row height <=0.07 then you can unhide a row as normal. Here is a link that explains. https://wmfexcel.com/2014/04/01/when-unhide-row-doesnt-work/.

Comment: @JvdV yes, I did research myself and stumbled upon the same link. The thing is, if I input the `RowHeight` manually (that means selecting the rows on the `Sheet -> RightClick -> Row Height...` then it does unhide the table. However, if I add the following line inside vba: `Rows(copy_start & ":" & copy_end).EntireRow.RowHeight = 12.75` then it doesn't work. It's as if it somehow didn't influence the RowHeight in sheet

Comment: @Rawrplus, what if you 1) Set Rowheight of your range to 0.01 then 2) Unhide your range, then 3) Set Rowheight of your range to 12.75?

Comment: That graph is a Pivot Graph? Pivot Tables and Pivot Graphs resize cells. Maybe that could explain your problem.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes indeed it is. And it does resize the cells a little. Is there a way to perhaps prevent it from resizing them? and JvdV, will try later on, unfortunately I no longer have access to the file atm (work HDD)

Comment: To be honest, best way IMO would be to have the Graph in a different sheet. Another option would be to move down some rows the blue table (it starts at row 21, move it to a row where the Graph does not affect it).

Comment: Please stop doing string math to pick a range of values. VBA includes a `.Resize()` method to be applied to `Range` or `Cells` in addition to `.Offset()` to select the top left cell and then expand the range by a specified number of rows and columns.